# I got an error while upload the data to API of doctype html invalid character ^

Tags: html, flutter, http, postman

[image]

Here is my code of hitting the API  and I am checking on local server.  It is working on Postman but on local it is not. I have tried all the Stack Overflow solutions but nothing is working for me. It is working on Postman but on local it is not. Every time it returns html doctype.

```
try {

      var url = Uri.parse(ApiRoutes.updateUserInformationApi);
      final response = await http.post(
        url,headers: headers,
        body: json.encode({
          "country": "Pakistan",
          "country_flag_id": "",
          "state": "Sindh",
          "city": "Karachi",
          "dob": "1990-05-15",
          "marital_status": maritalStatus,
          "latitude": latitude,
          "longitude": longitude,
          "religion": religion,
          "sub_religion": subReligion,
          "prayer": prayer,
          "appearance": {
        "height": "175",
        "weight": "70",
            "skin_color":  "white",
            "hijab": 1,
            "smoking":  0,
            "beard":  0,
            "body_type" : "smart"
          },
          //appearance,
          "financial_status": "Stable",
          "my_specification": "Kind-hearted and ambitious",
          "partner_specification":  "Caring and understanding",
          "monthly_income": 3000,
          "ethnicity": "sindhi",
          "phone": "+923001234567",
          "langs_speak": "English, Urdu",
          "about_me": "I am a software engineer passionate about creating meaningful applications.",
          "willing_to_relocate": "yes",
          "profile_pic": "image.png",
          "education":  "Grdauate",
          "children": "1",
        }),
        //json.encode(body),

      );
      print("data1");

      print(response.body);

      var data = json.decode(response.body);

      print("data2");
      print(data);

      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("data2 underresponsecode");
        if(data['user'] != null) {
          UserModel userDataModel = UserModel.fromJson(data);
          log("profile updated ${userDataModel.user?.toJson()}");
          userController.userData = userDataModel;
          LocalDataHelper().saveUserAllData(userDataModel);
          return true;
        } else {
          showShortToast(data["message"]);
          return false;
        }
      }
      else {
        showErrorToast(data['message']);
        return false;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("exception $e");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.